# Javascript/Typescript update data from one nested array in another

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

My initial array is like this:

```
 preData = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 0],
    ['FALLBACK', 0],
    ['IDLE', 0],
    ['OUTOFSERVICE', 0]
];
```

The array with values is like this:

```
preData = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 2],
    ['IDLE', 3],
];
```

I would like to update the values of first array from the second one, the result:

```
  finalData= [
        ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 2],
        ['FALLBACK', 0],
        ['IDLE', 3],
        ['OUTOFSERVICE', 0]
    ];
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions would be converting initial array to `Map`, updating it and converting it back to array:

```js
const preData = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 0],
    ['FALLBACK', 0],
    ['IDLE', 0],
    ['OUTOFSERVICE', 0]
];

const valueData = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 2],
    ['IDLE', 3],
];

const map = new Map(preData);

for (const [key, value] of valueData) {
    map.set(key, value);
}

const result = Array.from(map);
console.log(result);
```

**Update** - typings could be:

```
const preData: ReadonlyArray<[string, number]> = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 0],
    ['FALLBACK', 0],
    ['IDLE', 0],
    ['OUTOFSERVICE', 0]
];

const valueData: Array<[string, number]> = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 2],
    ['IDLE', 3],
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I fix error: Argument of type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[any, any]>' when building the release?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map()` and `.forEach()` method of arrays:

```js
let arr1 = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 0],
    ['FALLBACK', 0],
    ['IDLE', 0],
    ['OUTOFSERVICE', 0]
];

let arr2 = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 2],
    ['IDLE', 3],
];

let updateArray = (a1, a2, map = new Map()) => {
  a1.forEach(arr => map.set(arr[0], arr));
  a2.forEach(arr => map.set(arr[0], arr));
  
  return [...map.values()];
};

console.log(updateArray(arr1, arr2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the the second array `actualData` content of index '0' with the original array `preData` index '0'. If it is a match, copy over that content from index '1' (the value) of `actualData` into the original array.

```js
var preData = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 0],
    ['FALLBACK', 0],
    ['IDLE', 0],
    ['OUTOFSERVICE', 0]
];
var actualData = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 2],
    ['IDLE', 3],
];

preData.forEach((ele, idx, arr) =>{
        actualData.forEach(item =>{
                       if(item[0] === ele[0]){
                           ele[1] = item[1];
                           arr[idx] = ele;
                        }
                   });
});
console.log(preData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over the preData array and check if a value exists for each value in the actualData array or not. If it doesnt, just push the default valye to the finalData array and if it does, add the value and then push it.

use **forEach** to iterate over the preData array and use **filter** to check if the data exists for each value in preData.

```js
    const preData = [
      ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 0],
      ['FALLBACK', 0],
      ['IDLE', 0],
      ['OUTOFSERVICE', 0]
    ];
    
    const actualData = [
      ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 2],
      ['IDLE', 3],
    ];
    
    const finalData = [];
    
    preData.forEach(preDataValue => {
      const index = finalData.push(preDataValue);
      const data = actualData.filter(d => d[0] === preDataValue[0]);
      if (data.length) {
        finalData[index-1][1] += data[0][1];
      }
    });

    console.log(finalData);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `.map` & `.find`

```js
preData = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 0],
    ['FALLBACK', 0],
    ['IDLE', 0],
    ['OUTOFSERVICE', 0]
];

preData2 = [
    ['APP_NOT_RUNNING', 2],
    ['IDLE', 3],
];

const finalData = preData.map(x=>{
  const found = preData2.find(y=>y[0]===x[0])
  if(found)
    x[1] = found[1]
  return x;
})

console.log(finalData);
```